# Selenium does not find all the matching elements, and returns a different number of elements each time

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to find elements.
Everything I tell it to find, it all returns an empty list.
Trying every way - xpath, tag_name, class.
The generalization returns empty lists, or each time a different number of elements.

[image]

I need the href of all the apartments.

first I tried the simple code (that worked all the time):

```
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(
        executable_path="C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\לימודים\\python\\selenium-   project\\Driver\\chromedriver.exe")
    driver.get("https://www.ad.co.il/nadlansale?sp3=30&sp1=1,82,41,103,28,101,110")
    driver.maximize_window()
    time.sleep(30)
    links_list = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="cards"]/div/div/div[2]/a')
    print(len(links_list))
```

I also tried by class_name, and nothing,
I also tried this code:

```
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(
        executable_path="C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\לימודים\\python\\selenium-   project\\Driver\\chromedriver.exe")
    driver.get("https://www.ad.co.il/nadlansale?sp3=30&sp1=1,82,41,103,28,101,110")
    driver.maximize_window()
    time.sleep(30)
    try:
        links_list = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="cards"]/div/div/div[2]/a'))
        )
        print(len(links_list))
    finally:
        driver.quit()
```

Comment: Make sure to have a `!` before your image so `![text][img link]` this will make the image display in your post without having to click on the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this xpath you should get all href

```
//*[@id='cards']//a
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
links_list = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//div[contains(@class, 'card-body p-md-3')]/a")
href_links = [link.get_attribute("href") for link in links_list]
print(href_links)
```